# How to performance test a desktop application using Visual Studio Ultimate load test

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing

I need to performance test a windows desktop app with Visual Studio Ultimate.

I've written coded UI tests to perform a computation on the app, [it's typically like- import a file, fill inputs on a form, click on a button, it will compute and generate desired output in a few seconds] 
What I need to measure (for different set of input files and values) are:

1. CPU usage while doing this computation
 2. Memory usage
 3. Time taken to do this computation for every input file

I have written coded ui tests, configured load test to measure #1 and #2, with transactions to measure the time to execute #3. Also the tests are data driven. 
How do I take a good performance report for this ? What are the counters to be added? and how to export this in a good simple xlsx report format ? I've been going through msdn articles but couldn't find them very helpful for this particular context. 
Note: There are no network calls. It's purely a standalone app, and only one user is going to use it.

Comment: Note: I am using VS Ultimate 2013

Comment: The counters you indicate as #1 and #2 are already provided in the "Controllers and agents" graph. No need to add any more. There are buttons just above the graph for exporting graphed data to Excel or CSV. What else do you want?